# reshape a numpy ndarray python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Let's say that I have an `ndarray` of shape `(10 x 1024 x 2)` presenting `10` vectors of `1024` complex values each value has a `real` and `imaginary` parts. and I want to reshape this array to `(10 x 2 x 1024)` meaning `10` vectors each vector has two arrays one for real parts and the other for imaginary.

I try with `reshape()` and `vstack()` but, the data looses the right order
and I am afraid if I use `swapaxes()`, I can encounter memory problems later since the data is actually bigger.

Anyone have an idea about how should I fix this issue?

Comment: Why would it be bigger?

Comment: because it is a part of a big dataset of shape `638976 x 1024 x 2`

Comment: A swapped/transposed array will have shape 638976 x 2 x 1024.  That's the same number of elements!  Swap/transpose makes a `view`, while alternatives using `stack` make a copy.  It's still likely that subsequent operations on that `view` will force a copy.

Comment: have you tried. `your_array.transpose(0,2,1)`??

Comment: @hpaulj I tried some functions yesterday and it seems that `transpose` and `swapaxes` do what i need. **Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 1024, 2)
a_t = a.transpose(0,2,1) #shape is (10, 2, 1024)
```